# Websocket is not working on few Window System

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc

Our website is based on webSocket(Port 9100) and working fine on HTTPS and multiple OS system.

But on some corporate provided system(laptops) for few users WebSocket connection could not be established but the same is working fine for other corporate users. It might be some local policy restriction on PC.

Please advise and help me out to understand the cause of this issue and its resolution.

Comment: Have you tried on multiple Browsers? According to my understanding websockets are supposed to be implemented in the browsers

Comment: Perhaps there's a firewall (either local windows firewall or corporate firewall) that is limiting connections on non-standard ports for "security" reasons?  It's pretty much impossible for us to know what's going on.  FYI, all modern browsers support webSockets, but versions of IE before IE10 do not.